# Filling DBGrid dynamically with related DataSource and DataSet (Delphi)

Tags: database, delphi, pascal, dbgrid

In my project i have 1 database with 20 DataSource & DataSet.
I would like to capture the customer name with "BGrid1.SelectedField.AsString;" and open another DbGrid2 with data (datasource and dataset) referring to the selected customer.
In sample below is working, but i have no idea how to do changing dynamically.

```
procedure TMain.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin 
   Form2.Caption := DBGrid1.SelectedField.AsString;
if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo = 1 then 
begin
 DBGrid2.DataSource := Form2.DtSource05;
  DBGrid2.DataSource.DataSet := Form2.ADO01;
   Form2.Show;
end;
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short: it's not supposed to work like that, this can be done without GUI controls involved (of course you wouldn't see anything then...). Have a look at this tutorial chapter about master-detail-relationship. I hope, it will help you! http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Master+Detail+Structures/